# How to solve this system of equation with two unknown?

Tags: polynomials

What is $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ?

$$\frac{\alpha}{(\beta^2+1)^{3/2}}=12$$
$$\frac{\alpha}{(\beta^2+0.06^2)^{3/2}}=10$$

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Divide the two LHS and solve first the founded equality for $\beta$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real root. If there were, $\alpha$ would have to be positive. And it is clear that for positive $\alpha$ and  real $\beta$, the left-hand side of the second equation is greatr than the left-had side of the first.

Comment: thank you very much for your hint.

Comment: You are welcome. You can solve for $\beta^2$ by dividing, cubing, and simplofying. You will get a cubic in $\beta^2$. This can be solved numerically (the Cardano formula is not practical). There will be one real solution for $\beta^2$, but it will be negative.